# how to use strstr()?

Tags: c++, strstr

i want to take data from file and store it in string array and and perform a search function with only few information like type"j" and the program able to look for data name which contain "j".
but my program cannot work.....
i am wondering am i using the strstr() correctly or not?

my text file :

```
Jason Derulo
5000
Martin Delux
8752
Justin Haber
51855
Alex Zander
52163
```

and

coding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct
{

    char name[30],adv_srh_name[30];
    double balance;

}ACCOUNT;


int main()
{
    ACCOUNT record[31]; 
    int choice,acc_amount=0;

    ifstream openfile("list.txt");              //open text file 
    if (!openfile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening input file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        ACCOUNT temp;
        int i = 0;
        double d = 0;

        while (openfile)
        {
            openfile.getline(temp.name, 30, '\n');

            //consume the newline still in the stream:    
            if ((openfile >> d).get()) { temp.balance = d; }

            record[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
        openfile.close();               //close text file
        acc_amount = i;
    }

    cout << "Please enter a client name:";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin.getline(adv_srh_name, 30);

        for (int j = 0; adv_srh_name[j] != NULL; j++)
            adv_srh_name[j] = toupper(adv_srh_name[j]);

        cout << adv_srh_name;

        for (int a = 0; a < acc_amount; a++)
        {
            if ((strstr(record[a].name, adv_srh_name)) != NULL)
            {
                cout << "Name :" << record[a].name << "\n";
                cout << "Balance :" << record[a].balance << "\n\n";
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use character arrays for strings. Use `std::string` unless you have very strong reason not to do so. The equivalent of `strstr` for `std::string` is the `find` member function.

Comment: As Wojtek mentioned you should use strings if you're using "using namespace std;" so here you can find anything you need http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string

Comment: When you say "cannot work" what do you see happening? BTW you do toupper on adv_srh_name but not the file you read in. What happens if you just print out the record name and balance regardless of the `strstr` result?

Comment: Your code kind of works with a few minor fixes - see [here](http://ideone.com/LAZtf4) - but the main thing is doctorlove's point that you're not converting your search term to uppercase, so things like "M" will find "Martin", but if you type "Martin" it'll search for "MARTIN" and match nothing.  `strstr` is *not* case insensitive.  You might want to see if your system has `strcasestr` (but then there's no need to change the search term to uppercase).

Comment: @WojtekSurowka the teacher want me to do in array string...no choice

Comment: @TonyD i'm not changing the search term to uppercase?that mean my strstr() match nothing in the if statement?doesn't toupper() will change it to uppercase?

Comment: @doctorlove all my input was in uppercase,i still ned to change them to uppercase again ?

Comment: Yes you are changing the search term, but you are not changing the text you read from the file - they won't match reliably unless you change both or use `strcasestr` or similar.